# Getting error "Object (NaN, NaN) has no method 'extend'" when extenting bounds for Google Map v3

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am getting an error **"Object (NaN, NaN) has no method 'extend'"**, when I try to extend the bounds for each of my markers on google map.

Here is some code:

First I declare the bounds globally:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Then I set each markeer using the following code

```
function displayMarker(appID, title, image, imageType, address, markerType, lat, lng, markersCount) {
    var listingLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: listingLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: markerType ? imgBluePin : imgGreenPin,
        title: title + address
    });

    bounds.extend(listingLatLng);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        { content: GetContent(title, image, imageType, address),
            size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

Them, when I load the page I get the error mentioned above when the code tries to extend the bounds,e.g. on line

```
bounds.extend(listingLatLng);
```

Why am I getting that error?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks right! Try 'for (var j in bounds) {console.log(j)}' in the console and investigate why the 'bounds' object doesn't have that method..

Comment: Could it be a problem with an individual marker that hasn't got values for lat and lng?

Comment: all the markers get correct coordinates

Comment: `bounds` could have been accidentally reassigned somewhere. It's a common bug when dealing with global variables. @wije's comment about debugging the variable should see if this has happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the bug. Except declaring bounds as

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

it was declared as

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLng();
```

which was wrong.